# MySQL batch file update

Tags: mysql, batch-file

One of my clients has an issue with his MySQL database. To solve the issue I need to just run a simple update on a table. I will need to send that to my client via a batch file.

How do I run a MySQL update on a table via a batch file?

Answer (score 2):

Typically I put the SQL commands that I want to use in a plain text file. You can then call the file by launching MySQL and:

```
\. filename
```

This will run each line of the file as if it was typed from input. It is also easy to test.

If you need more, you can launch MySQL via a command they can cut and paste and pipe the file into MySQL as the input. Make sure usernames and passwords are handled by your command line or your script.

Comment: Or excecute the command file from the prompt `mysql> SOURCE myfile.sql;`

Comment: What @BrianHooper said works perfectly. I used to set the complete path by the way

Answer (score -1):

the following is more preferable.

On Linux:

```
    mysql -u root -p -D database < file
```

I have been using this and I find it more convenient.